# Convert string to decimal with point or comma based on current culture

Tags: c#, decimal, culture

Depending of **browser language** I am getting string like

> 123.22
>
> or
>
> 123,22

So sometimes I am facing an exception here

```
Convert.ToDecimal(item.UnitPrice);
```

I would like to create some expression so the convertion should be done based on current culture. Is it possible to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't tell us what is your [`CultureInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) but anyway..

Let's assume your [`NumberFormatInfo.NumberDecimalSeparator`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.numberdecimalseparator%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is `,` instead of `.`

Your string `123,22` works well like;

```
string s = "123,23";
decimal d = Convert.ToDecimal(s, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture); //123,23
```

If your string is `123.22`, then you can use [`String.Replace`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk49wtc1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method for replacing `,` instead of `.` like;

```
string s = "123.23";
if(s.Contains('.'))
   s = s.Replace('.', ',');
decimal d = Convert.ToDecimal(s, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture); //123,23
```

Comment: And if your string is `1,123,23` ??

Comment: @thinco OP didn't tell such a string.

Answer (score 0):

`Convert.ToDecimal()` is already using the `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture`, it is just not set to the same value as the browser.

You could try specifying in the `web.config` file that the current culture be inherited from the browser: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bz9tc508.aspx

Usually a better direction would be to make sure the browser submits consistent values not depending on the browser language.